# Python 3.7.4 -> How to keep memory usage low?

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

The following code retrieves and creates and indexes of uniqueCards on a given database.

```
for x in range(2010,2015):
    for y in range(1,13):
        index = str(x)+"-"+str("0"+str(y) if y<10 else y)
        url = urlBase.replace("INDEX",index)
        response  = requests.post(url,data=query,auth=(user,pwd))

        if response.status_code != 200:
            continue

        #this is a big json, around 4MB each
        parsedJson = json.loads(response.content)["aggregations"]["uniqCards"]["buckets"]

        for z in parsedJson:
            valKey = 0
            ind = 0
            header = str(z["key"])[:8]

            if header in headers:
                ind = headers.index(header)
            else:
                headers.append(header)

            valKey = int(str(ind)+str(z["key"])[8:])

            creditCards.append(CreditCard(valKey,x*100+y))
```

The `CreditCard` object, the only one that survives the scope is around 64bytes long, each.
After running, this code was supposed to map around 10 million cards. That would translate to 640 million bytes, or around 640 Mega bytes.

The problem is that midway this operation, the memory consumption hits about 3GB...

My first guess is that, for some reason, the GC is not collecting the `parsedJson`. What should I do keep memory consumption under control? Can I dispose of that object manually?

Edit1:
the CreditCard is define as

```
class CreditCard:
    number = 0
    knownSince = 0
    def __init__(self, num, date):
        self.number=num
        self.knownSince=date
```

Edit2:
When I get to 3.5 million cards on `creditCards.__len__()`, `sys.getsizeof(creditCards)` reports 31MB, but the process is consuming 2GB!

Comment: More likely each `CreditCard` object costs way more than only 64 bytes. What exactly makes you think they're around 64 bytes? And how far is "midway"? And what's the code for `CreditCard`? And are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Python?

Comment: the credit card object is composed of 2, 8 digit ints, so I think the 64 byte measurement is correct... midway is around 2013 (the outer loop)... never made to 2014... im using 64 bit python

Comment: I just tried `(12345678).__sizeof__()` on a 64-bit Python and it said 28 bytes. So those two ints alone are already 56 bytes. References to these numbers, the `CreditCard` object itself, and the references to the cards all cost extra. No way that all together fits into 8 bytes.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof(CreditCard(valKey,x*100+y))` says 64, but OK, lets take into consideration that is 128. 3gb still more than double the expected 1.2gb...

Comment: Does a `CreditCard` keep any other references? Its code you added to the question is clearly not the whole code, as there's no constructor.

Comment: no, the init has been updated to reflect the whole code

Comment: What are those "headers"? How many different ones are there?

Comment: the header is the first 8 digits of a credit card. These are assigned by an consortium. Right now, we allot a grand total of 7 different headers. In order to save memory, I created a map, pointing to a single digit int

Comment: You *can* use the `gc` object to force garbage collection to occur immediately ...

Comment: You could save *some* space by creating each `knownSince` only once. That is, create `knownSince = x*100+y` at the start of the loop and then use that single object for all cards (of that date).

Comment: actually no, this is the "Map" part of a map-reduce. Once finished, ill reduce and the last "known-since" is a very important info for me. understand "known-since" as recharge date for now

Comment: Huh? What do you mean? It's not like I proposed to not store the dates in the cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the `json.load`. Loading a 4MB results in a 5-8x memory jump.

Edit:

I manage to work around this using a custom mapper for the JSON:

```
def object_decoder(obj):
    if obj.__contains__('key'):
        return CreditCard(obj['key'],xy)
    return obj
```

Now the memory grows slowly and I've been able to parse the whole set using around 2GB of memory

Comment: That shouldn't stay in memory long. Once you reassign the variables in the next loop iteration, the old data isn't needed anymore and its space can be reused. Try putting `continue` after the `parsedJson = json.loads(...)` so you're only loading and don't keep anything. How high does your memory usage get then?

Comment: basically the same... I even tested loading a single Json adding a loop to simulate some work and giving time for the garbage collector to act, but it didn't went down